# Meaning of 'only then'

Tags: expressions, differences

Is there any difference in meaning between

> check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only then.

and

> check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only in that case.

?

Which is the correct way of expressing that the checked condition must fulfil, and not merely predate the invocation?

Comment: *check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only in that case.* is not idiomatic. ++ *check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only then.* has the wrong word order. It should be *check that newSnap != m_snap and **only then** invoke onSnapEnter."*

Comment: The idiomatic way is probably "if newSnap is not equal to m_snap, call onSnapEnter" but that's probably a duplication of your code.  If this is a code comment, it's not adding value.  If there's a reason why you don't want to call onSnapEnter for a snap is not actually new, you should probably be explaining that here instead.

Comment: I think you are modifying a different sentence;
*check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter then and only then.*
Corresponding to the logic of *if and only if*. 
This could well mean to go ahead and invoke onSnapEnter in any event so long as they checked the value of newsnap first. I think in common use this would not be the case but computer folks rely on precision. I would use Greybeard's word order to be sure.

Comment: @Greybeard Could you please post your comment as an answer, so I could accept it?

Comment: @vines Your wish is my command... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only in that case.* is not idiomatic.

*check that newSnap != m_snap and invoke onSnapEnter only then.* has the wrong word order.

It should be *check that newSnap != m_snap **and only then** invoke onSnapEnter.*